# Access Categories for each entry of a specific channel in ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine, categories

So, I am still trying to figure out how to use expression engine and I want to create a list of all of the entries in a channel, which includes the corresponding categories. I can create the list as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="custom_channel"}
   <div style = "display:block;padding:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #999999;">
      <span>Title: {title}</span><br>
      <span>Date published: {entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</span><br>
      <span>Access: {access}</span><br>
      <span>Type: {type}</span><br>
      {!--Here is where I am trying to access the corresponding 
          categories for each of the entries--}
   </div>
   {paginate}
          <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
   {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So, what this does currently is it goes through the entries and creates the html as defined for each entry. I've tried to include {categories} and other related tags but have not been successful. I have looked online and have not been able to find anything related. **Is it possible to access the corresponding categories for each entry? If so, how?** Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [categories variable pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories). Incidentally, if you're looking to tap into the ExpressionEngine community, post your questions to [expressionengine.stackexchange.com](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really sure where to look.